# OpsHub | error in execution of job

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm using opshub 1.0 to migrate a tfs project to the cloud,
sourcecontrol only.

I'm getting this error:

> Error in execution of Job : TFS| TFS| TFS Source 1400241279585 Source TFS 1400241279586 'xxxx' Commit Information  TFS| TFS Source 1400241279585 Source TFS 1400241279586 TFS Commit Information
>
> unexpected char: '%' [select eaiEventsLogged.sourceEntityId from com.opshub.dao.core.SourceFailed where ('$/xxx/packages' like concat(file_path,'%') or '$/xxx/xxx' like concat(file_path,'%') or '$/xxx/xxx.Azure' like concat(file_path,'%') or '$/xxx/xxx.Data' like concat(file_path,'%') or '$/xxx/xxx.iPad' like concat(file_path,'%') or '$/xxx/xxx.Models' like concat(file_path,'%') or '$/xxx/xxx.Products' like concat(file_path,'%') or '$/xxx/xxx.Reporting' like concat(file_path,'%') or '$/xxx...

Answer (score 1):

We have determined this is a defect. The utility is not handling the case where the file name has special characters properly.

This issue is resolved in the next version (which should be available in the Visual Studio Extensions Gallery in about 1 week). We will update this post once the new version is available.

If your error doesn't align with the root cause above, please add additional details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The just released (6/2/2014) 1.0.1.001 version seems to fix this issue.

Get it here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2